# Output matplotlib plots from saving

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I found a tutorial online for this `matplotlib` and `numpy` graph. The code runs smoothly, but there is no output. I have tried to save the graph as a file, but that does not seem to work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
zline = np.linspace(0, 15, 1000)
xline = np.sin(zline)
yline = np.cos(zline)
ax.plot3D(xline, yline, zline, "gray") # Data for three-dimensional scattered points
zdata = 15 * np.random.random(100)
xdata = np.sin(zdata) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(100)
ydata = np.cos(zdata) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(100)
ax.scatter3D(xdata, ydata, zdata, c=zdata, cmap="Greens");
def f(x, y):
  return np.sin(np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2))

x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 30)
y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 30)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(X, Y, Z, 50, cmap='binary')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z');
theta = 2 * np.pi * np.random.random(1000)
r = 6 * np.random.random(1000)
x = np.ravel(r * np.sin(theta))
y = np.ravel(r * np.cos(theta))
z = f(x, y)
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z,cmap="viridis", edgecolor="none");
```

The link to the website is https://www.edureka.co/blog/python-projects/. Surely there is some way to access the graphical user interface to display the plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `plt.show()` at the end will display both of the graphs.